# How do I get audio CD to open in iTunes for ripping?

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes

I have a Macbook Pro (latest version) and iTunes 10.1.1.  I have the preferences set in iTunes to prompt to import an audio CD when it's inserted into the drive, and my System Preferences set to throw audio CDs over to iTunes, but whenever I put in an audio CD, it just starts playing (and not through iTunes).  I don't see any other players pop up w/ controls, either, and if iTunes isnt' already open, it doesn't open but I see the same behavior (i.e. music starts playing).

Any ideas of what I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Can you use Expose to show all of the windows running? Have you tried with different CDs, to make sure it isn't one of those CDs that has an application on that just plays the music.

I've just tested with the same settings as you (System preferences - Music CD, open iTunes and iTunes, Ask to import) and all it did was open iTunes.

Another possibility, have you got any other media player applications running?